# ORDS 3.0.12 could not be installed along with Database 11G XE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I tried to install latest ORDS (not standalone)  by following steps but could not succeed as Database 11g XE could not connect.
When i tried to login with sysdba in 5 number steps then says invalid logon.
**NOTE: Still also i can not login with XE in browser like localhost:1521/xe.
but in command prompt i can login with database.
I also checked tnsnames.ora , listener.ora where everything was correct.**

```
1. go to cd e:\apex
login as sysdba:
alter user apex_public_user account unlock;
alter user apex_public_user identified by Database#1;
2.rename file ords.war to apex.war
3. Install APEX Listener : (e:\ords)
java -jar apex.war
location for configuration data = e:\ords
hostname: localhost
DB port: 1521
database SID [1] 2
SID[XE] xe
username [APEX_PUBLIC_USER]:
password [APEX_PUBLIC_USER]: Database#1
```

- *`**5.Please login with SYSDBA privileges to verify Oracle REST Data Services schema.**`*
  [image]

Comment: so if you open a sqlplus prompt there to xe service, connecting as SYS, it lets you in?

Comment: sqlplus sys@xe as sysdba and its login

Comment: @ZishanCse did you issue `lsnrctl status` and get `Instance "XE", status READY` ? If not, problem maybe related to `LISTENER`

Comment: Maybe try sqlplus sys@ex and see if you get the ORA-01017 when you don't login as sysdba. I think if you login as sysdba through the network it uses the password file and when you login normally through the network it uses the database password. May depend on REMOTE_LOGIN_ PASSWORDFILE setting.